# OAuth server token endpoint gives back 404

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

I'm working on token-based authentication and authorization between my SPA and web services. I found great articles in this topic written by [Taiseer Joudeh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3625265/taiseer-joudeh) and based on [this](http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/) I started to build up my infrastructure.

The Resource and Authentication servers are separated. The authentication server has two endpoints:

- http://dev.dilib.local/services/authentication/api/audience -- I can add new audience
- http://dev.dilib.local/services/authentication/oauth2/token -- I can generate the token

The first one works properly, so I can register new audience. I have issues with the second one. It gives back 404, always.

```cs
public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                //only dev environment
                //TODO
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/services/oauth2/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                Provider = new CustomOAuthProvider(),
                AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat("http://dev.dilib.local")
            };

            appBuilder.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        }
```

As you can see it is almost the same as was written by Taisser in his article.

What I have done so far in order to find that why it is not working as it is expected:

- I double checked the code I coded, it is ok
- I googled around and there are a few people who met this issue but the answers only indicated that they could solve it, nobody made the effort to write down what he/she did
- I changed the TokenEndpointPath a few times to avoid the case it may conflicts with other service running on my machine, however, I'm don't have any other service on my machine
- I have read that the OAuth endpoint is not exactly a service endpoint and I saw a code snippet, but the whole article was about CORS and I did not want to mix everything
- I checked the IIS logs, nothing but the fact the particular POST and the 404
- I checked the event viewer, nothing
- I checked the related questions here but nothing

So, I run out of thoughts, I assume I made something silly, and I would like to ask your help!

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that the oauth2 token endpoint URI is as below but your code snippet is not saying this as code seems to be missing "authentication" string in the "TokenEndpointPath" variable which you created. I have pasted the corrected code below. I am not sure if your problem was that simple :)

> http://dev.dilib.local/services/**authentication**/oauth2/token

```
OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                //only dev environment
                //TODO
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/services/authentication/oauth2/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                Provider = new CustomOAuthProvider(),
                AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat("http://dev.dilib.local")
            };
```

Comment: Ohh, I pasted the wrong code here. You are right, they do not match. However, not this is the problem. I don't know yet what is the problem. When I started to work on this issue again having my machine untouched for the night, the token endpoint answered for the first a few requests, after that I got the 404 again. I went through another tutorial written by also Taissen, and now I have a working token endpoint, but is not separated from the webapi server. I'm happy now. Later, I'll spend a little time to refactor it.

Comment: As you mentioned that "the token endpoint answered for the first a few requests, after that I got the 404 again", I think this behavior is related to "the user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting")". It seems there is a limit on the number of requests you can send within the some amount of time. However, server should return "429" http status in this case but not "404".

Comment: @SayusiAndo glad that my posts were useful, but I guess there is no rate limiting applied by default in Web API projects, throttling and rate limiting something you should implement.